# Inserting employee records

Tags: c#, linq

There is nothing wrong, but is there a nicer way to re-write this program?

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> InsertEmployee(dynamic employees)
        {
            var newEmployeeRecord = new List<Employee>();

            foreach (dynamic employee in employees)
            {
                newEmployeeRecord.Add(

                    new Employee
                    {
                        EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.EmployeeId)
                        ,
                        EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(employee.EmployeeName)
                        ,
                        Age = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Age)
                        ,
                        Salary = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Salary)
                        ,
                        DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.DepartmentId)
                    }
                );
            }
            return EmployeeRecords.Concat(newEmployeeRecord);  
        }
```

Also, can we avoid typecasting? (I think it's not possible, so it could require an extension method.)

Comment: It helps to provide some plain English explanation of what the code is supposed to do. Part of a code review is to verify it does what you think it does. Without the explanation from you, all we know about the code is what it actually does, instead of what it should do.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`?

Comment: And, you should probably include the `Employee` class. Converting what seems to be `Int32` to `Int32` and `String` to `String` makes no sense.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Since `employee` is `dynamic` rather than having any type, its members are `dynamic` also, and so must be converted to the appropriate type in order to compile. The run-type type identification will choose the correct converter overload.

Answer (score 3):

Looking this over a second time, I see a few more problems, one of which was my mistake.

I believe that `InsertEmployee` is a bad name, since the number of employees inserted depends on the input parameter. A better name is `InsertEmployees`. Similarly, `newEmployeeRecord` is a bad name since it's also about an arbitrary set of employees, but it's extraneous anyway.

I notice that this code `throw`s an exception if any of the `Convert.To*()` fails, maybe due to the CEO making $3 billion a year, or employeee IDs changing to have 10 digits. you mention wanting to avoid the type conversion, was this the main idea or was it speed?

I had missed the line about `EmployeeRecords`. What is it? It's not defined anywhere in the code provided; we can determine from context (though we shouldn't have to) that it is `IEnumerable<Employee>` or a derived class and that it's either a global, or a member of the same class that `InsertEmployee()` is, and that no matter what its protection status is, it's available to anyone who can call `InsertEmployee()`, which is everybody. Which brings up two questions: (a) why does it need to be `return`ed from `InsertEmployee()` if it's accessible everyhwere that `InsertEmployee() is`? Just make it `public`. (b) Why wouldn't `InsertEmployees` just `.Add` the `Employee`s directly to it?

```
public void InsertEmployees(dynamic employees)
{
    foreach (dynamic employee in employees)
    {
        EmployeeRecords.Add(new Employee
        {
            EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.EmployeeId)
            ,
            EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(employee.EmployeeName)
            ,
            Age = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Age)
            ,
            Salary = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Salary)
            ,
            DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.DepartmentId)
        });
    }
}
```

But let's get to the real underlying issue, why this whole code stinks. Several commenters hinted at the absurdity of using `dynamic` here. It's clear that you know the database schema; thus there's no reason to be using `dynamic`. .NET has good language features for working with database natively and in a strongly typed manner; it's called LINQ-to-SQL. Use it; you'll do less grunt work and have better code. Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Old answer (incorrect, given that I missed what the function was `return`ing):

Since you're returning an `IEnumerable<>`, you can simplify things greatly by using [`yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) to give elements back one at a time, rather than creating a temporary `List` and then throwing it away:

```
    public IEnumerable<Employee> InsertEmployee(dynamic employees)
    {
        foreach (dynamic employee in employees)
        {
            yield return new Employee
                {
                    EmployeeId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.EmployeeId)
                    ,
                    EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(employee.EmployeeName)
                    ,
                    Age = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Age)
                    ,
                    Salary = Convert.ToInt32(employee.Salary)
                    ,
                    DepartmentId = Convert.ToInt32(employee.DepartmentId)
                }
            );
        }
    }
```